# Trabajar con varias peticiones al servidor [Asincronidad] ¿SetTimeOut,Promesas...?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy trabajando con varias peticiones AJAX , algunas a PHP , otras a txt...

El problema viene a la hora de trabajar con los datos devueltos de estas peticiones para formar algo en conjunto ( como una tabla) .¿Como puedo trabajar con toda la información a la vez ?

Investigando un poco he encontrado este [articulo](http://lemoncode.net/lemoncode-blog/2018/1/29/javascript-asincrono) que recomiendo su lectura que basicamente me da dos soluciones :

1. CallBacks
2. Promesas

Los callbacks me parecen una solucion chapucera y terriblemente ineficiente , pero las promesas son realmente interesantes pero aun probando ejemplos no me queda nada claro como realmente utilizarlos.

Os pongo un ejemplo rapido en el que lo estoy probando :

```
window.onload = function(){
 var global="nulisimo";
 var global_segundo="nulisimo_2";

 //Cargo el primer TXT 
 cargar_txt();
 var global = procesar_txt();

 //Cargo el segundo TXT
 cargar_txt_segundo();
 var global_segundo = procesar_txt_segundo();

 setTimeout(function(){
 console.log("Global primera :",global);
 console.log("Global segunda :",global_segundo);
 }, 2000);

Promise.all([procesar_txt(), procesar_txt_segundo()])
.then(resultArray => console.log("Valores globales :",global,"/",global_segundo))
.catch(e => console.log(`Error capturado:  ${e}`));

}
```

Cargar TXT es la peticion AJAX en si , y respuesta lo unico que contiene es esto :

```
function procesar_txt() {
if(peticion_http.readyState == 4) 
{
    if(peticion_http.status == 200) 
    {
        var cadena = peticion_http.responseText;
        console.log("La cadena en el 1 es  :",cadena);
        return cadena;


    }
  }
}
```

No consigo que me devuelva los valores de las funciones , ni por CallBacks ni por promise . ¿Alguna idea o ejemplo de como manejar resultados de varias peticiones AJAX? 
PD:¿Es la manera correcta de tratar respuestas con return?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que he visto en el código, he notado que las funciones que pasas a `Promise.all([])` no resuelven ninguna promesa.

El método `Promise.all([])` recibe un iterable de promesas, con lo cual cada una de tus peticiones deben de retornar una promesa, de esta forma el método `Promise.all([])` resolverá cuando cada una de las funciones que recibe estén resulta.

Te muestro un ejemplo parecido.

```js
var procesar_txt = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve('RESUELTA PRIMERA PETICIÓN');
    }, 2000);
  })
}

var procesar_txt_segundo = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve('RESUELTA SEGUNDA PETICIÓN');
    }, 5000);
  })
}

//Cargo el primer TXT 

Promise.all([procesar_txt(), procesar_txt_segundo()])
  .then((result) => {
    alert(result.join(','));

  })
  .catch(e => alert(`Error capturado:  ${e}`));
```

Es casi tu mismo código, sólo que he añadido una promesa a cada función.